# Error para iniciar sesión

Tags: php, html, session

Cuando accedo directamente a carrito.php el usuario puede entrar directamente aun sin haber iniciado sesión, estoy tratando de poner el código con un condicional para que cuando se acceda a carrito.php, salga el mensaje de que "No se ha iniciado sesión", obligándole a regresar de nuevo a inicio.php para que la inicie.

No obstante, aunque ponga dicho condicional, el codigo no funciona bien y no hace lo que le indico que haga con los nuevos condicionales, ni sale el aviso de que la sesión no ha sido iniciada.

```html
<?php
    //INICIO DE LA PÁGINA
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tienda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<!--FORMULARIO DE LOS PRODUCTOS A VENDER-->
    <h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>
    <form id="inicio" method="post" action="carrito.php">
        <p>Selecciona el producto que quieres comprar:</p>
        <select name="articulo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Libreta">Libreta</option>
            <option value="Boligrafo">Boligrafo</option>
            <option value="Grapadora">Grapadora</option>
            <option value="Tijera">Tijera</option>
            <option value="Carpeta">Carpeta</option>
            <option value="Cartulina">Cartulina</option>
            <option value="Estuche">Estuche</option>
        </select>
        <p>
            <label for="nombre">¿Cuantos quiere comprar?</label>
            <br />
            <input type="number" name="number" id="number" size="15" max="10" min="0" value="0">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Añadir al carrito" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">
        </p>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php
//INICIAMOS LA SESIÓN
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["carrito"]))
{
    $_SESSION["carrito"]=[];
}
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST["number"]; $i++)
{
    array_push($_SESSION["carrito"], $_POST["articulo"]);
}
if (!isset($_COOKIE["pedidos"])) 
{
    setcookie("pedidos", 0);
}
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
if(!empty($_SESSION["carrito"]))
{
    setcookie("fecha", date("d/m/y G:i:s"));
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Carrito</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION["carrito"]))
        {
            echo "USTED NO HA INICIADO SESIÓN";
        }
        //ASIGNAMOS ARRAY DE LOS PRECIOS Y TOTAL
        $precios = [1.50, 0.50, 3.00, 0.90, 0.20, 0.10, 5.50];
        $total = 0;
        echo "<img src='assets/img/carrito.png' class='carrito'/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<p class='carritoTexto bg-danger'>TU CARRITO<p>";
        //SI EL CARRITO ESTA VACIO
        if(empty($_SESSION["carrito"]))
        {
            echo "<span class='vacia'>Su cesta está vacía</span>";
        }

        //SI NO ESTA VACIO
        else
        {
            //AVERIGUAMOS QUE COMPRA RECORRIENDO EL ARRAY DE CARRITO CON SUS ARTICULOS
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION["carrito"]); $i++)
            {   
                echo "<tr><td class=bg-primary>Articulo " . ($i + 1) . "</td><td class='bg-warning'>";
                echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$i] . "</td>";

                //SEGÚN LOS CASOS, ES UN PRODUCTO U OTRO
                switch($_SESSION["carrito"][$i])
                {
                    case "Libreta":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[0] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/libreta.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[0];
                    break;

                    case "Boligrafo":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[1] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/boligrafo.jpg'/></td>";                   
                    $total += $precios[1];
                    break;

                    case "Grapadora":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[2] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/grapadora.jpg'/></td>";                    
                    $total += $precios[2];
                    break;

                    case "Tijera":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[3] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/tijera.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[3];
                    break;

                    case "Carpeta":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[4] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/carpeta.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[4];
                    break;

                    case "Cartulina":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[5] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/cartulina.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[5];
                    break;

                    case "Estuche":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[6] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/estuche.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[6];
                    break;

                    
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            
        }


         //Si se accede mediante url nos invita a ir a la página de inicio


        ?>
        </table>

        <br/>
        <div class="total">
            Total: <?php echo $total . "€"; ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <button onclick="location.href='inicio.php'">Seguir Comprando</button><br/><br/>
        <form action="pedidos.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="total" value=<?php echo "$total"?> />
            <input type="submit" value="Gestionar pedido" name="gestionar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usa # para comments en PHP. // es para JavaScript.

Comment: @Duston // también sirve para php

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas abrir y cerrar los bloques PHP contiguos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo he logrado solucionar, aunque me parece un poco "chapucera" como solución, pero como tal, funciona y cumple el propósito de alertar al usuario de que no ha iniciado sesión.

```html
<?php
//INICIAMOS LA SESIÓN
session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION["carrito"]))
    {
        $_SESSION["carrito"]=[];
    }
    if(!isset($_POST["number"]))
    {
        echo "NO HA INICIADO SESIÓN.";
    }
    else
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $_POST["number"]; $i++)
        {
            array_push($_SESSION["carrito"], $_POST["articulo"]);
        }
    
    }

    if (!isset($_COOKIE["pedidos"])) 
    {
        setcookie("pedidos", 0);
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    if(!empty($_SESSION["carrito"]))
    {
        setcookie("fecha", date("d/m/y G:i:s"));
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Carrito</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <?php
        //ASIGNAMOS ARRAY DE LOS PRECIOS Y TOTAL
        $precios = [1.50, 0.50, 3.00, 0.90, 0.20, 0.10, 5.50];
        $total = 0;
        echo "<img src='assets/img/carrito.png' class='carrito'/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<p class='carritoTexto bg-danger'>TU CARRITO<p>";
        //SI EL CARRITO ESTA VACIO
        if(empty($_SESSION["carrito"]))
        {
            echo "<span class='vacia'>Su cesta está vacía</span>";
        }
        //SI NO ESTA VACIO
        else
        {
            //AVERIGUAMOS QUE COMPRA RECORRIENDO EL ARRAY DE CARRITO CON SUS ARTICULOS
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION["carrito"]); $i++)
            {   
                echo "<tr><td class=bg-primary>Articulo " . ($i + 1) . "</td><td class='bg-warning'>";
                echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$i] . "</td>";

                //SEGÚN LOS CASOS, ES UN PRODUCTO U OTRO
                switch($_SESSION["carrito"][$i])
                {
                    case "Libreta":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[0] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/libreta.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[0];
                    break;

                    case "Boligrafo":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[1] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/boligrafo.jpg'/></td>";                   
                    $total += $precios[1];
                    break;

                    case "Grapadora":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[2] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/grapadora.jpg'/></td>";                    
                    $total += $precios[2];
                    break;

                    case "Tijera":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[3] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/tijera.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[3];
                    break;

                    case "Carpeta":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[4] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/carpeta.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[4];
                    break;

                    case "Cartulina":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[5] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/cartulina.jpg'/></td>"; 
                    $total += $precios[5];
                    break;

                    case "Estuche":
                    echo "<td class='bg-success text-dark'>" . $precios[6] . "€</td>";
                    echo "<td><img src='assets/img/estuche.jpg'/></td>";
                    $total += $precios[6];
                    break;

                    
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        </table>

        <br/>
        <div class="total">
            Total: <?php echo $total . "€"; ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <button onclick="location.href='inicio.php'">Seguir Comprando</button><br/><br/>
        <form action="pedidos.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="total" value=<?php echo "$total"?> />
            <input type="submit" value="Gestionar pedido" name="gestionar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```